# Use AppleScript to select eraser in Powerpoint

Tags: macos, applescript, powerpoint

First, [here](https://youtu.be/hkxV8Et-QDU) is a video explanation of my problem.

I am a teacher searching for a way to easily access the Eraser tool while giving presentations with PowerPoint. Partly following this [guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote), I have tried using Automator to record my actions when I select the eraser, saving this as a Quick Action, and then assigning a keyboard shortcut to the action.

Unfortunately, I get the error:

> The action "Watch Me Do" encountered an error: "Application Powerpoint is not running when it is expected to"

Or, if I first copy the code from the Automator action, paste it into a Run AppleScript file, then set a shortcut to execute the file, I get this:

> The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.Automator error -212.)”

Can anyone help please? Thank you!

Alternatively, if anyone knows of a better way to achieve my goal, please do share.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to go through each process one step at a time to isolate what is generating the errors. First let’s see if this code will select the eraser tool.
Paste this following AppleScript code into a new Script Editor.app document. You can run the code directly from that document.  If the code works for you then tried pasting it into your Automator workflow.

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate
    repeat until frontmost
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    repeat while not (exists of radio button 3 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "PowerPoint")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    if not (exists of menu button "Eraser" of group 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "PowerPoint") then
        click radio button 3 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "PowerPoint"
        delay 0.1
        if value of menu button 1 of group 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "PowerPoint" is 0 then
            click menu button "Eraser" of group 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "PowerPoint"
        end if
    else
        delay 0.1
        if value of menu button 1 of group 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "PowerPoint" is 0 then
            click menu button "Eraser" of group 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "PowerPoint"
        end if
    end if
end tell
```

[image]

Make sure you add Automator.app, Script Editor.app, System Events.app, and PowerPoint.app… as well as your script (if it was saved as an .app) to the System Preferences > Security > Privacy > Accessibility application list. Then add again those same items to the System Preferences > Security > Privacy > Full Disk Access application list.

[image]

Also, if you save your script or Automator workflow as an application, anytime you make changes and save that file again, you will need to go back and re add it to those application lists in the security preferences again.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me with this. I have attempted your suggestion but I'm still getting that first error `"Application PowerPoint is not running when it is expected to.”` Should I change my Powerpoint version perhaps? Thanks again.

Comment: My version of Microsoft PowerPoint for Mac is version 16.34 (20020900) .  And I am using macOS Catalina Version 10.15.3 (19D76).  I’m also adding a few items to my post, about security preferences, which may make a difference.

Comment: I have now gotten it to work like yours! Thank you again. My hope though is for a way to trigger the eraser while in Presentation mode. There is currently no shortcut for this, and trying to click on the bottom-left menu to grab the eraser is near impossible on a Smartboard. Are you able to point me in the right direction? I can't thank you enough!!

Comment: ( I have tried recording the action using automator, copying the code underlying each action, and using that to replace the second two-thirds of your script. This does not appear to work. I imagine there are several syntax problems that I do not recognize)